# How to get a text message, email, or phone call without knowing the number or email?

Tags: android

I want to know how to set up a way to contact others without knowing the other persons phone number or email.  Like for example make a craigslist style app and not everyone want to provide their phone number or email but would like to have easier way for others to contact them if selling an item.  How can I get up a way for someone to post an ad and provide the phone number or receive texts or phone calls without others seeing the info.  So if others search for example craigslist and come across ones ad they can contact them quick with a text or phone call just by clicking a button but won't see the number they are calling.  Is there a way to do that, and with sending an email as well?   Do you think making users set up an account may be easier?  If someone can provide an example of how this is done would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to block the user from seeing the number they are calling/texting. The only way to get around this that I see would be to create a sort of proxy server with a universal phone number. The user would text your universal number and include the ad id number in the message. The server could receive the text and forward it to the proper person.

Comment: OK thought so well what about using a proxy server?  How might one set that up?  Or is that to broad of a question?